# .gitignore exception not working for one directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` file in root directory

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
!portal
!app.js
!node_modules
!README.md
```

All exceptions are working except for `portal`. I added `portal` later to this file (It wasn't there from the beginning). But `git add .` doesn't add that folder and its content. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git ignore patterns are recursive by default, so `*` matches not just files in the root directory, but also files in subdirectories. To have rules apply only to the current directory you'll want to prepend `/`.

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
/*
# Except this file
!/.gitignore
!/portal
!/app.js
!/node_modules
!/README.md
```

**Tip:** [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) is a handy tool to have on hand when you're having trouble with your `.gitignore` rules. It can tell you what files are being excluded and, with the `-v` option, the origin of the exclusion rules.

Comment: It is working for all other items. Like node_moduls, which is a directory and has content in it. It's not only working for portal directory. I tried your solution. Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Does `portal` contain files? What are they named? Git doesn't track directories, only files, so there needs to be at least one file to add, and it mustn't match the `.gitignore` rules above.

Comment: JohnKugelman yes John there are a lot of files in there. This is the weird part.

Comment: What does `git check-ignore -v portal` show?

Comment: It shows that portal directory is ignored

Comment: No they don't exist in my GitHub repo after pushing

Comment: It should tell you the exact `.gitignore` line that's at fault.

Comment: Right. My bad. It says line 5 has an error `.gitignore:5:!portal  portal`. So what error is that? Everything seems normal

Comment: You tried putting `/` in front of everything, and it didn't work? It works when I try it.

Comment: I tried `/` and also moved the line to the end of file. Again `.gitignore:8:!/portal  portal`

Comment: Try experimenting in a new empty project. Here's what I did: (1) Make a new empty directory and run `git init`. (2) Create a single file with `mkdir portal; touch portal/test.txt`. (3) Add the `.gitignore` file from your question. (4) Run `git status` and see that that `portal/` is ignored. (5) Edit `.gitignore` and change `*` to `/*`. (5) Re-run `git status` and see that `portal/` is no longer ignored.

Comment: Converting `*` to `/*` solved the problem. That was a weird issue! Thanks!